# Is it possible that C# arrays are overflowing in memory and overwriting each other?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm trying to write a program in C# that parses a large text for new file names, and renames a list of files to the names obtained from the text file.

So in my program, we see something like this:

```
string[] newNames = parseNames(txtFileName.Text);
string[] previousNames = getFileNames(txtFolder.Text);
```

Where in newNames we have 900+ names in the format similar to "01208265-9", while in previousNames we are supposed to have the same number of filenames in the old format similar to "Video1001".

This is what the function getFileNames looks like:

```
    private string[] getFileNames(string inputText)
    {
        //get the file names of all the files in the folder
        //note, does not contain path, only file names
        string[] FileNames;

        DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(txtFolder.Text);
        FileInfo[] Files2 = folder.GetFiles("*.avi");

        FileNames = new string[Files2.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Files2.Length; i++)
        {
            FileNames[i] = Files2[i].Name;
        }
        nameCompare comparer2 = new nameCompare();
        Array.Sort(FileNames, comparer2);
        return FileNames;
    }
```

Its a pretty simple function that takes in the path to a folder, and pulls in all the file names in that directory, then it sorts the names and returns the array.

The problem is, when I run the code, I see this problem:
[image: Notice the first entry]

Note the first entry in the array. I double, triple, and quadruple checked to ensure that there is no file of the new format in the folder. This issue only pops up when I run the program on a larger data set of 900+ files.

I am honestly stumped and the only possibility in my opinion has to be that there is something wrong with DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() which I find unlikely, since that is part of the .net core libraries, or that there is an issue with C# memory management, that somehow weirdly enough the previous array is overwriting the first entry in my new array.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Occam's Razor: The file with the new-style name exists in the folder, but you just haven't found it. Maybe "view hidden and system files"?

Comment: A quick sanity check can never hurt: `var found = File.Exists(Files2[i].Name);`

Comment: One kind of thing that has seemingly happend to me over and over again: first run, break into it, single step, some items get renamed, stop debug for some reason. Next time, break into it, wonder why there is new name already... Just an idea

Comment: Not sure if this has to do with your problem, but the `inputText` parameter is not being used. Instead, the function is hard-coded to always read the value of `txtFolder.Text`.